# How do i make 2 people access the same db (android app dev)?

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio

i'm making an android app where 2 people ,with different account, can access the same database and read some data (the data is all text). Now i'm asking how can i do that. Is it better if i make a remote db and than make the devices access to the database, and if so how can i do that whitout killing my server? Or there is any other way to do this? Ty

Comment: Yes, you want a db hosted on a server. There are lots of free "serverless" options, e.g. Firebase Firestore.

Comment: OMG TY. i was blowing my mind in to pieces. I didn't know about that. I have a pretty nice server but i didn't want to generate traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to combine SQLite with Firebase. Check [this post](https://github.com/jirawatee/FirebaseStorage-Android/issues/1) for a reference.